# Como se usa o cin.get() em C++?

Tags: c++, string

eu gostaria de saber mais sobre a função cin.get() e também a diferença entre ela e a função getline() pois sempre que vou pesquisar algo relacionado a isso me aparecem mais resultados de busca falando sobre a getline() do que a cin.get().

Se poderem...deixem uma resposta detalhada :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método retorna um tipo `int` com valor igual ao do caracter lido na stream de saída, valendo não exclusivamente para `cin` mas para qualquer `istream`.

```
char c = (char)cin.get() ;
```

O código acima faz o mesmo que o seguinte, que salva o caracter numa variável passada por referência, não por cópia.

```
char c ;
cin.get( c ) ;
```

Há uma terceira opção que faz o mesmo.

```
char c ;
scanf( "%c" , &c ) ;
```

Há outros métodos e também funções com o mesmo propósito, inclusive com diferenças como a possibilidade de capturar do console somente uma tecla (sem precisar de enter para pegar um caracter) e podendo ainda exibir ou não o caracter teclado.

Também tem vários métodos `get` de streams de entrada que servem para capturar outras coisas. Vou listá-los a partir da fonte (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get) e explicar.

O `int get()`, como expliquei, retorna um inteiro que é resultado da captura de um caracter no stream de entrada.

O `istream& get ( char& c )`, como expliquei, salva por referência no argumento `c` o resultado da captura de um caracter no stream de entrada. Além disso, retorna o próprio objeto stream usado caso pretenda invocar novamente algum método.

O `istream& get ( char* s , streamsize n )` salva uma string num array `s` de caracteres (para de capturar os caracteres da string ao atingir o tamanho limite inteiro `n` ou ao encontrar `'\n'`) e retorna o próprio stream para invocar mais métodos na mesma linha.

O `istream& get ( char* s , streamsize n , char delim )` salva uma string num array `s` de caracteres (para de capturar os caracteres da string ao atingir o tamanho limite inteiro `n` ou ao encontrar o caracter `delim`) e retorna o próprio stream para invocar mais métodos na mesma linha.

Os métodos `istream& get ( streambuf& sb )` e `istream& get ( streambuf& sb , char delim )` são como os dois anteriores, mas ao invés de salvar num array ele salva numa estrutura de buffer.

Alguma dúvida?

Comment: Então cara, você esclareceu algumas das minhas dúvidas só que no código abaixo eu não entendi o porquê de nós precisarmos passar como parametro o tamanho do nosso vetor na chamada da função cin.get():                                                                                                      #include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  
  char name[50];
  
  std::cout << "What is your name?\n";
  std::cout << "My name is: ";
  std::cin.get(name,50);
  std::cout << "Hello " << name << "\n";
  
  
}

Comment: Acontece que existem vários métodos com o mesmo nome cuja assinatura se diferencia pelos parâmetros. O `name` não é um char, é um array de chars. Neste caso, está chamando `istream::get( char* , int )`, ou seja, vai capturar não apenas um caracter mas sim uma string (com o limite de 50 caracteres incluindo o caracter nulo ao final) e salvar em `name`.